# Calculating NDVI value per pixel using GEE and extracting to CSV

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, pixel

I'm new to GEE.

I would like to calculate NDVI value **per pixel** for a set of S2_SR images and extract the values to a CSV file.

```
Pseudocode:
1. import S2_SR image collection(start date X, end date Y).
2. clip every image to a specific polygon that I have previously imported.
3. calculate NDVI value for every pixel in the clipped image.
4. output the calculated NDVI values to a CSV file.
```

(Let's say the clipped image is 100x100m size, which means we have 10x10 pixels. So the CSV file should be pixels 1-100 and their values).

My code so far is built like this:

```
//IMPORT SEN2 IMAGE
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR') 
  .filterDate('2019-09-01','2019-09-30')
  .filterBounds(poly)

// Define an index function (return only NDVI).
var NDVI = function(image) {
  return image.expression(
    '(NIR - RED) / (NIR + RED)', 
    {
      'NIR': image.select('B8'), 
      'RED': image.select('B4'), 
    }).rename('NDVI').copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames());
};

// Calculate NDVI for each image
var NDVIS2 = S2.map(NDVI)

// Empty Collection to fill
var ft = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List([]))

var fill = function(img, ini) {
  // type cast
  var inift = ee.FeatureCollection(ini)

  // gets the values for the points in the current img
  var ft2 = img.reduceRegions(poly, ee.Reducer.first(),30)

  // gets the date of the img
  var date = img.date().format()

  // writes the date in each feature
  var ft3 = ft2.map(function(f){return f.set("date", date)})

  // merges the FeatureCollections
  return inift.merge(ft3)
}

// Iterates over the ImageCollection
var newft = ee.FeatureCollection(NDVIS2.iterate(fill, ft))

// Export
Export.table.toDrive(newft,
"anyDescription",
"anyFolder",
"anyNameYouWant")
```

But the result I get is a value for each image taken,
As you can see here:
[image: CSV OUTPUT]
(I have selected only one of my fields in the displayed CSV output but it is the same for all.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call `ee.Image.reduceRegion()` on your NDVI image with an `ee.Reducer.toList()` reducer.

```
var region = ee.Geometry(Map.getBounds(true))
  .centroid(1).buffer(50).bounds(1)

var ndvi = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-02-01')
  .map(function (image) {
    return image
      .normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4'])
      .updateMask(image.select('QA60').not())
  })
  .median()
  .rename('ndvi')

var ndviFeatures = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(ndvi
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
    geometry: region,
    scale: 10
  })
  .get('ndvi'))
  .map(function (ndvi) {
    return ee.Feature(null, {ndvi: ndvi})
  })
)

print(ndviFeatures.aggregate_array('ndvi'))
Map.addLayer(ndvi, {min: 0, max: 1, palette: 'red,orange,yellow,green'}, 'ndvi')
Map.addLayer(region, {}, 'region')
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ndviFeatures,
  description: 'ndvi',
  selectors: ['ndvi']
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/1a8225792714b648a346ef43a5feefb7

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel. It seems you have answered my question just as I have edited the question with my latest code written. I will try you version of the code, could you please check mine as well?